# How to use groupby().apply() instead of running loop on whole dataset in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large dataset, which looks like below:

```
Year         Company              Sales          Dummy          

1993            A                  100             1  
1994            A                  50              1 
1995            A                  50              1  
1996            A                  NaN             0
1997            A                  NaN             0
1998            A                  NaN             0

1993            B                  100             1  
1994            B                  50              1 
1995            B                  50              1  
1996            B                  NaN             0
1997            B                  NaN             0
1998            B                  100             1
```

The expected output is like:

```
Year         Company              Sales          Dummy       

1993            A                  100             1            
1994            A                  50              1            
1995            A                  50              1            
1996            A                  NaN             0            
1997            A                  NaN             0            
1998            A                  NaN             0            

1993            B                  100             1            
1994            B                  50              1            
1995            B                  50              1            
1996            B                  NaN             1            
1997            B                  NaN             1            
1998            B                  100             1            

1993            C                  100             1            
1994            C                  50              1            
1995            C                  50              1            
1996            C                  NaN             1            
1997            C                  32              1            
1998            C                  100             1
```

I want to fill 1 in Dummy column for some companies like company B and C because company B has missing values between the sample period, but company B and C have sales value available again at end of the sample period.

I used this code:

```
*** Create Dummy variables        
    df['Dummy']=np.where(df.Sales.notnull(),1,0)       

*** Def a function 
    def Newdummygenerator(x):
        for i in range(len(x)):
             if x.iloc[i,x.columns.get_loc('Dummy')]==1:
                x.iloc[i,x.columns.get_loc('Dummy')]=1
             elif x.iloc[i,x.columns.get_loc('Dummy')]==0 and\ sum(x.Dummy[i:])>=1 and sum(x.Dummy[0:i])>=1:
                x.iloc[i,x.columns.get_loc('Dummy')]=1
             else: 
                x.iloc[i,x.columns.get_loc('Dummy')]=0
```

*** run for loop on company
            for i in df.Company.unique():
                Newdummygenerator(df[df.Company==i])

Above codes work fine and serve my need. However, my dataset is very large. Above codes take an age to run. 
I try to use:

```
df.groupby('Company',as_index=False).apply(Newdummygenerator)
```

or

```
df.groupby('Company',as_index=False).apply(lambda x: Newdummygenerator(x))
```

Above codes do not work.

And also

```
df.groupby('Company',as_index=False).apply(lambda x: Newdummygenerator(x))

Output: __
```

Questions:

1. The output of the above code is __; I wonder why this is the case. From my understanding apply() function take every group as a sub-dataset, and my function can do some operation for each sub-dataset. Do I have any misunderstanding?
2. If I want to use the defined function, how can I change my defined function to use apply() function?
3. Is there a more efficient way to do it?

Quick classifications: The problem I deal is much complicated than the situation that I described. 
My point is why I cannot use the defined function like above in the groupby().apply() function? 
Thank you so much!

Comment: Does the first value in dummy for a  group have to be 1?  If not must it be labeled as 1 also, aswell as the rest of dummy values within the group?

Comment: Hi Yatu, no it does not to be 1, if the first year sales of the firm do not available, the dummy should be 0. The dummy for missing values is one if the missing values are between two available sales.

Comment: Okay its a little tricker then, let me update @yufeng

Comment: Thank you so much yatu. Sorry for the unclear in my last post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know how to solve this problem.

My defined function should return a new data frames because I aggregated data by group and need a new dataframes in this case.

If I do not put return, pandas will only do aggregate, therefore your output will be '__'

```
*** Create Dummy variables        
    df['Dummy']=np.where(df.Sales.notnull(),1,0)       

*** Def a function 
    def Newdummygenerator(x):
        for i in range(len(x)):
             if x.iloc[i,x.columns.get_loc('Dummy')]==1:
                x.iloc[i,x.columns.get_loc('Dummy')]=1
             elif x.iloc[i,x.columns.get_loc('Dummy')]==0 and\ sum(x.Dummy[i:])>=1 and sum(x.Dummy[0:i])>=1:
                x.iloc[i,x.columns.get_loc('Dummy')]=1
             else: 
                x.iloc[i,x.columns.get_loc('Dummy')]=0
        return x
```

Above defined function is able to plug into the apply() function

```
df.groupby().apply(Newdummygenerator)
```